# Mixing Higher or Lower resolution TS on HLS for better QoS

Tags: android, streaming, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, mpeg-dash

I want to implement a system where Segments will be dynamically populated on M3U8 playlist for HLS, based on user's connection speed. The thing is, if I add Segments with various resolutions, it results in lots of Frame drops and sometimes it Freezes or Crashes the application which streams the M3U8 playlist (In my case, Exoplayer). Is there any way by which I can achieve seamless streaming with minimal frame drops and high QoS?

Comment: Were you able to achieve facebook/linkedin like news feed with autoplay of videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds very much like [adaptive streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming), which [HLS supports](http://hlsbook.net/adaptive-streaming-with-hls/).

Encode your video at whatever bit rates you want to support and create a playlist for each variant. Then add the location of each playlist created in the previous step to a [master playlist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AboutHTTPLiveStreaming/about/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013978-CH3-SW12). The player will automatically switch between streams based on factors such as the available bandwidth.

Comment: You mean to say like, if I have 4 different bitrates, I have to provide everything on the master file and Exoplayer will take care of switching between bitrates considering the bandwidth?

Comment: And I have this weird scenario where I can have only one m3u8 file mentioning ts files with different bitrates as a list! is such kind of implementation possible?

Comment: In response to your first comment, yes. Listing 4 on the page I linked to about master playlists has an example of what one looks like. Take a look at the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag, which may help with your scenario.

Comment: @Simon We have adaptive videos but in a recyclerView in an android app what would be the optimal way to play them instantly.